# How to get httpOnly (secure) cookies TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, testing, cookies, e2e-testing, testcafe

For test purposes, I have to retrieve HttpOnly and Secure cookies right after successfully authenticated. As expected, `ClientFunction(() => document.cookie)` doesn't work. Since TestCafe is a proxy there should be a way to get access to that kind of cookies. How can I get there?

Answer (score 4):

At this moment, TestCafe does not have the capability to get secure cookies. We have a feature suggestion for this. Please follow the https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4428 issue.

Comment: You can actually work around this issue by intercepting http requests.  I access secure and httpOnly cookies by logging requests, and specifying headers and body in the options (since I need the JSON payload in the body as well as the cookies).

Answer (score 2):

My work-around is to use a RequestLogger.  For example:

```
import { Selector, RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

// Want everything from example.com
const logger = RequestLogger(/example.com/, {
   logResponseHeaders: true,
   logResponseBody: true
   // Do not set stringify response body if your response
   // comes as gzip or brotli or whatever, instead you
   // will need to use Node's zlib to unzip it and read it
});

fixture `My test`
   .page `https://example.com`
   .requestHooks(logger);

test(`Log in and retrieve cookies`, async t => {
   
   await t
   // Do things here
   .click(...)

   const requests = logger.requests
   for (const req of requests) {
       console.log('Headers: ', req.response.headers)

       for (const cookie of req.response.headers['set-cookie']) {
          // You will have to parse the cookie yourself
          console.log(cookie)
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @James-Young. I do exactly the same as a workaround. But it is still painful because I need to use RequestLogger for each fixture

Comment: It certainly is a pain isn't it?  I am thinking I will need to fork testcafe so I don't have to use this work-around in future because TestCafe is taking so long to fix it (issue has been open for two years!)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 1.19.0, TestCafe offers a dedicated cross-browser cookie management API that allows you to manipulate browser cookies using flexible and convenient methods even if the `HttpOnly` flag is specified.

The following example demonstrates how to get all page cookies with the `Secure` and `HttpOnly` attributes.

```js
 let cookies = await t.getCookies({ 
    secure: true,
    httpOnly:  true
 });
```

Read more about TestCafe cookie management in the [d](https://testcafe.io/403938/release-notes/framework/2022-05-26-testcafe-v1-19-0-released#cookie-management)[ocs](https://testcafe.io/403938/release-notes/framework/2022-05-26-testcafe-v1-19-0-released#cookie-management).